# SSAS: Same cube, worse performance on more powerful server

Tags: performance, ssas, database-performance, sqlperformance

I have a unexplained issue that's haunting me for weeks;
There is a SSAS cube that's not performing well on any customer server, same sub-par performance on Staging and Production environments, but the **same exact cube** with the same exact data brought to our internal testing server, which is way less powerful than the customer Production servers, performs better.

The same exact MDX queries **performs 50% better on our Test server which is about 25% slower** than the production server.

I checked the server settings, the queries created by the application, disk IO performance, reprocessed the Cube, but nothing seems to explain this difference.

The I/O performance would have explained this difference, but this explanation had to be discarded because benchmarking with dskspd showed that their server have faster IO anyway.

Someone has some idea on what I can verify next?
I'm running out of ideas :/

Thank you

Comment: Multidimensional or Tabular? Do you have specs on the servers? CPU model and sockets? Is power saving mode on in the BIOS or in the Windows power settings?

Comment: Multidimensional model;
I have the specs:
The server is a HP ProLiant DL360p
CPU: Intel Xeon CPU E5-2650 @ 2.00GHz, 1995 Mhz, 8 Cores, 8 Logical X 2
RAM: 128GB
Storage: SAN VNX 7500 - Tier 1 except backup drive (I thought that this could be the issue but...)

Haven't asked for bios power saving settings yet

Comment: what about the other server's CPU specs? On power saving mode read this article and note how to determine if the CPU is running at top speed: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/10/sql-server-on-powersaving-cpus-not-so-fast/

Comment: Our test server is on a Hyper-V machine with 16 logical cores (Xeon E3-2640  @2Ghz) and 32Gb of Ram; Our storage is in a SAS drive too but with slower 7200rpm Raid1 Drives;  The major difference is that we're using Windows Server 2008R2 while on the Prod Server is installed Windows Server 2012R2 , can it have some kind of impact?

Comment: I would run Geekbench or similar tools to compare single core performance between the servers. I would also restart the SSAS service and retest to see if the production server has a fragmented heap which is slower than after restart.

Comment: when you run the test MDX queries do you see one core pegged or many? If one core then you are probably formula engine bound so what matters most for performance is single core performance.

Comment: I would expect a newer OS would perform better not worse given identical hardware. But maybe there is a bug you are hitting. Are you on the latest cumulative update on both servers?

Comment: That's it! It was the Power Configuration!
In balance mode it had 50% worse performaces, the CPU wasn't scaling up under load at all, let me upvote you :D

Comment: great! I posted that as an answer. Feel free to mark it as the answer if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you check power saving mode. Read this [article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/10/sql-server-on-powersaving-cpus-not-so-fast/) and note how to determine if the CPU is running at top speed.

I would run Geekbench or similar tools to compare single core performance between the servers.

Comment: That was it, it had a MASSIVE impact on the MDX performance, we're talking 100% improvement by switching from "Balanced" to "High performance"